# Google Drive SDK currently supports only Http for Realtime APIs

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api, google-realtime-api

Latest news coming from iOS-> https://techcrunch.com/2016/06/14/apple-will-require-https-connections-for-ios-apps-by-the-end-of-2016/

Anybody from google-drive-sdk support can tell if there is a plan to support https for Realtime APIs soon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run realtime APIs in https URIs. I don't see any problem with that. [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) is referring to website security. It's an added encryption layer of SSL/TLS to protect the traffic. So it should be ok.

If you check the [Google Realtime API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/realtime-quickstart#step_1_set_up_the_sample), you can see https is always used.

A Googler even runs his realtime API samples in HTTPS in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mlaov3J4hDA).

Note: Transitioning from HTTP to HTTPS doesn't magically happen. Here's [a guide to that](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6033049?hl=en&ref_topic=6033084). Even local servers are not exempted.

Comment: Can you please tell whether in following steps from [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/realtime-quickstart#step_1_activate_the_drive_api): 

4. Insert http://localhost:8000 as the authorized JavaScript origin.
5. Insert http://localhost:8000/oauth2callback into the redirect URIs field ,

Should be working fine when changed to https?

Comment: with http server configured to support https right?

Comment: HTTPS don't just automatically work like I mentioned, even for local servers. For example if you just add 's' on your 'http' to make it 'https' it won't work. There's a process. If you're using Nodejs, [try this link](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/).

Comment: My site has always used https with the realtime api, no problems. Google is definitely on a continuous push towards https eg: they rank your site higher if has ssl. Why would you not want it? It's a kindness to your users anyway, and doing it early in the process means one less disruptive change (in ranking, links etc) later.